# Recursive query based on array column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table with parent and child as columns, my parent column is an array because the child can have multiple parents. So could anyone suggest on how to build cte (Postgres 11.2) to get parent and ancestors of a child.This is my data. The cte should return the correct parent irrespective of the array position.

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    parent_id uuid[],
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The data is

```
id       parentId  

1        null      
2        null      
3        1         
4        1         
5        1         
6        [3,4]     
7        2         
8        6
```

Expected output for the `id=8`:

```
parent

 1
 [3+4]
 6
```

Comment: "parent" or "parents"? Please be precise. Disclose your version of Postgres, the exact table definition, and the exact desired result.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter ok, added the details

Comment: @user8532998 can you add a better sample? your table expects `uuid` and `uuid[]` and your data sample uses `int` and `int[]`. Prefereably, add an `INSERT` statement to the table you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your test case:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE ancestry AS (
   SELECT parent_id
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  id = 8   -- your id here
   
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT t.parent_id
   FROM   ancestry a
   JOIN   tbl t ON t.id = ANY (a.parent_id)
   WHERE  t.parent_id IS NOT NULL
   )
TABLE ancestry;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b9dad27fb7b06f25d9b1899caad309d5)*

The query does not, however, merge elements of multiple distinct arrays on the same level. Your test case is not revealing in this respect. You probably have to do more. But you'll first have to define exactly what's allowed in the data and how to deal with duplicates in multiple ancestry arrays on the same level.

Comment: You are right, the next bummer is elements with distinct parents in the same level, which is the case when 3 and 4 are from different parents instead of 1. In that case  How can i group the last level of ancestor as one record.

Comment: @user8532998: Improve the question as suggested if you need more.